# How to get the value of a variable from a callback function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I want to get the contacts value from my a callback function.

How to have my `this.recherche = contacts` ?

```
App.provider('ContactsP', function() {

this.$get = function() {
  return function(search) {

    console.log('Factory ContactsCtrl RECHERCHE : ' + search);

    this.recherche = [];
    this.options = new ContactFindOptions();
    this.options.filter = search;
    this.options.multiple = true;
    this.fields = ["displayName", "name", "phoneNumbers"];

    navigator.contacts.find(this.fields, function(contacts) {

      //I want to put contacts into this.recherche but that doesn't work....

     this.recherche = contacts; return contacts;

    }, function(e) {
      console.log("Error finding contacts " + e.code)
    }, this.options);

  };
};
```

Comment: What javascript library are you using?

Comment: I wont work because 'this' is another context then. You could store 'this' in a variable and used that inside the callback.

Comment: It looks like `.find` my be an asynchronous function. In that case, have a look at [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call).

Comment: Hi, thank you. 
It's on angularJS and Cordova.
Felix : I try and tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you are in the callback your reference to `this` is not your enclosing object. You need to use [`angular.bind`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bind) to pass in the context of your object.

```
navigator.contacts.find(this.fields, angular.bind(this, function(contacts) {

      //I want to put contacts into this.recherche but that doesn't work....

     this.recherche = contacts; return contacts;

    }), function(e) {
      console.log("Error finding contacts " + e.code)
    }, this.options);
```